# Find parent commit of GitHub pull request

Tags: git, github

GitHub automatically creates two references when you submit a new pull request:

- `refs/pull/<number>/head` which points to the last commit added to the pull request
- `refs/pull/<number>/master` which points to a commit that GitHub creates to merge the current master with the current pull request head

These are the only ones, as shown by `git ls-remote`: there are only head and master.

I would like to find something like `refs/pull/<number>/parent` that points to the specific parent commit of this pull request.

My solution so far: download the special URL `<github>/pull/934.patch`, grep the contents of this file for the first SHA, and then use git to find the parent of this commit. Is there a way to do this without hitting the network?

Comment: When you say "parent commit", do you mean the common ancestor between the two branches?

Comment: Unless your pull request is pretty weird, it will be a branch off of master. So by parent commit, I mean I want to find the commit in master that this PR is built on top of. I suppose that is common ancestor, but if you just say common ancestors then you would get a number of other items too if the PR has been merging in master along the way

Comment: ...right? I would love to be proven wrong :)

Comment: Hi Hamy, you're not actually supposed to add solutions back into your question, solutions go into answers, or add a comment to your question. Also, pull-requests [***are not*** specific to GitHub](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project#Public-Small-Project), you can create pull requests with Git itself using [`git request-pull`](http://jk.gs/git-request-pull.html).

Comment: Oops, removed. Interesting link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use the [GitHub API for PR](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-commits-on-a-pull-request) to list all commits of a Pull Request (instead of downloading the `.patch`).

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/commits
```

Then, if you are in the repo, you can use git to get the parent of the first commit in that list (the commit from which the PR was initiated).

```
git log --pretty=%P -n 1 <commit>
```

Comment: Yea, the API would likely be more stable than the patch file. This is basically doing the same thing I'm already doing though - I guess (as the concept of PR is Github specific) there is no way to do this without hitting the network. Accepting this to close our the question, thanks!